# Redirect any Sub folder to root

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Here is the situation:

I need to redirect www.mydomain.com/anything/test.txt to www.mydomain.com/test.txt.

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^.*/test.txt" />
               <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please spare some time learning the basics of IIS Manager. Its Test pattern dialog can tell you what is "R:1" and "R:3" in just a few seconds, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns Your current expression in `match` tag makes it impossible to use such references. Learn from the examples and think carefully why they work and yours don't.

Comment: Hello lex li, thanks for your reply... i am new to this... i tried, but it seems tough... perhaps, having a solution... would be a much better idea...

Comment: As per rule i created {R:1} = my domain name and {R:3} is test.txt with this match pattern /(.*)/(.*)/(test.txt)